# Ruby console alternative for IRB (Windows)

Tags: ruby, console, irb

I am looking for some free light-weight GUI alternative for IRB console on windows. What I whould like to see:

1. Area to write a script (so I can edit, run, edit...)

- Command line to play with current variables
- Output window to see results
- Intellisence
- Breakpoints/debugging is a plus

Actually, some thing similar to powershell_ise.exe whould be great.

[image: Powershell ISE]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.co.il](https://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/scriptfanatic/WindowsLiveWriter/48e74fc0142c_B193/iseeditor_thumb_1.jpg))</sub>

P.S. I am **not** looking for IDE (NetBeans, Aptana, etc.)

Comment: You have an odd definition of lightweight.  What's wrong with IRB?  It could be adapted to do most (if not all of those).

Comment: One of my students was using something like this the other day. Don't know what it was though.

Comment: @rampion. Point 1 is missed. Also, for some reason, after some time arrow keys stop working.

Comment: how would you feel about bimodal - flip back and forth from your script to the irb interface?  It'd be pretty easy to add an 'edit' command to irb.  Plus, irb can already use 'load' to run arbitrary files.

Answer (score 1):

How does SciTE fail? Kinda curious because it feels like what you are looking for if you are working from a file. Ctrl-F5 executes, etc.

Comment: Hm.. With 'ruby-debug' it seems to be pretty powerfull. Thought, one strange thing happens. When I invoke debugger and type some thing, the letters are duplicated. (rdb:1) bbaarr. Don't you you have an idea?

Comment: Hey Alex. Unfortunately, no. I typically either use irb raw from the command line (in which case I've not experienced duplicate echo) or I put my text into a file and copy-past to irb or just run the file.

Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [e-texteditor.](http://www.e-texteditor.com/)

It isn't a full IDE, but it allows you to execute Ruby code, and either put the input inline, after a #=> comment, or into a new window.

You get some of what you want, not so much the debugger and console.  But the run-inline thing helps out a bit there.

It is based on TextMate, which is just fantastic.  But OS X only.  Oh, and it costs money.